# Is it possible to have methods like this in java? Or is it just some "dummy" method from the book to show example?

Tags: java, methods

What does following Java method -  method1  do in general? It doesn't have return parameter (because void). Does it just modify  input  parameter (int a) to the value stated in body of the method (6)? Or does it just take some int a as input and modify some global parameter a to the input value?  What is the point of such methods?

```
public void method1 (int a){
    a = 6;
}
```

Comment: It may be example showing that Java is **pass-by-value** and not pass-by-reference because after executing `int x = 1; obj.method(x);` value of `x` would stay the same (would still be 1).

Comment: Write some code and test the method to see what happens in different scenarios

Comment: There isn't much point except perhaps as part of a tutorial.  Essentially it does nothing.  (As suggested you could just try it out and see what happens.)

Comment: @markspace  That was the main point of my question. What should I type in to see output of the method that does nothing? Without proper knowledge I can only guess what it does.

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks. I think I found useful link  [Java passing a reference by value](https://jonskeet.uk/java/passing.html)

Comment: You can use a debugger and step through your code.  Most IDEs have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that code snippet is senseless, when considered out of context.  Likely there is a larger lesson being taught in your textbook, but we can only guess as to what that might be since we don’t have your textbook.

The method receives a primitive (not an object) variable holding some number. The only line of that method then discards that passed value, and replaces it with the number `6`. This makes no sense for two reasons:

- We discarded the value being sent to us by the calling programmer. That calling programmer is trying to message us, but we ignore the content of that message.
- We do no further work. After assigning six to the variable, it goes out of scope, to be garbage-collected eventually. No productive work was accomplished.

Be clear that we did *not* change anything in the calling programmer’s [state](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_(computer_science)#Program_state). When our method completes its execution, our variable `a` goes out of scope, and our value `6` disappears in a puff of smoke.

By the way, adding `final` to that argument declaration would tell the compiler to flag the re-assignent of the argument variable to a different value.

```
public void method1 ( final int a ){ …
```

Comment: Just nit-picking, the primitive variable is allocated on the stack and immediately deallocated when the method returns without garbage collection being involved.

Answer (score 2):

The point is probably to talk about call by value, and the subtle differences that come into play when using primitive types, as in your example, or reference types, like here.

```
int someA[] = ...
foo(someA);
```

with

```
void foo(int a[]) { a[0] = 1;
```

or

```
List<Whatever> someA = ...
foo(someA)

void foo(List<Whatever> a) { a.clear()
```

will actually have an effect in the place that `foo()` is called.

In other words: the method shown in the question is really a no-op, it doesn't do anything that can be observed outside (nicely explained in the other answer).